# What is the difference between MongoDB executionTimeMillis vs response time

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, explain

After reading the internet I am still not sure.

Using different tools like mongo command line or Robo 3T GUI I see that my query takes about **70ms** to provide results.

At the same time if I use explain it gives me executionTimeMillis at **14ms**

The connection is already established, so there should be no overhead there and yet the difference is around X5.
What are your thoughts?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but `executionTime` is the time what is needed database engine for execution of the query itself, find missing doc, make an aggregation and so on. And response time, it `exection+RTT`

Answer (score 1):

[explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis)

Total time in milliseconds required for query plan selection and query execution.

**Response time:**

Time between start and end of the query. It includes below times.

Time taken for processor cycles if any[wait time] + executionTimeMillis[plan selection, execution]  + Time taken to return the response[returning the last byte of the response]

Comment: Hola, Gibbs! So... I guess in my case 50+ms are "time taken to return the response"? Something based purely on server capacity / load at the moment?

Comment: Yes, if you have less servers than the resource needed to handle the request, if your ram is less which results more page swapping, all adds time to it. If you are connecting to remote mongo server via robot, then your local Internet could also cause this